# windows phone : grab audio samples

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I know I can play audio with MediaElement on wp7/8. 
I'm looking for a way to grab audio samples. 
By audio samples I mean decoded samples not the raw mp3 stream for example.
How can I do that ?

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is no.

The longer answer is that would of course be possible if you implemented an audio decoder (e.g. MP3) as part of your app.

Comment: Thanks Paul. What about WASAPI stuff [link](http://bit.ly/YQUXzj) or media foundation stuff [link](http://bit.ly/13hhzyA) or AudioSink [link](http://bit.ly/XAwEoi). With WASAPI it seems I can capture audio samples from the 'audio endpoint' see IAudioCaptureClient. With media foundation, it seems I can play audio from c++ and grab samples (IMFSampleGrabberSinkCallback). AudioSink provides everything for accessing samples. For these 3 cases I didn't find any examples showing if we can play an audio file and capturing samples. So I don't know if I'm wasting my time investigating these apis.

Comment: Those APIs are for capturing audio from the microphone, not from the audio stack on the phone.